# Creating bugzillas for failed tests on Jenkins?

Tags: hudson, bugzilla

We have a Jenkins enviroment running for a while and we create a bugzilla for each failed test to inform developers that something went wrong and he needs to correct that test. For now, we create this bugzilla manually but i would like to do it automatically.

Is there any plugin for Jenkins for that? Or i need to develop that using bugzilla API?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SQA, gcoelho.  Do you want Jenkins to log a new bug every time a test fails?  For example, suppose Jenkins runs once a day.  On Monday, a test35 fails, so you log a bug.  Suppose this particular bug will take a few days to fix.  Do you want Jenkins to log new bugs about test35 on Tuesday, Wednesday, and Thursday?  (This may be an improbable scenario in your organization, so my question may not be important.)

Comment: We try to fix broken tests the same day we detected them. Of course, sometimes this is not possible. The best option would be to not open a new bugzilla but that is ok too to open a new one because i can always close it as duplicated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you have any advice, user246?

Comment: Sorry, gcoelho, I did not find a way to do that.  I am only a casual Jenkins user though, not an expert.  Have you tried checking the Jenkins mailing lists (http://jenkins-ci.org/content/mailing-lists)?

Answer (score 2):

In theory you could configure [Jenkins to send emails](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) (see [this too](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/The+new+EMailer)) to an email address that [bugzilla is monitoring to create/update bugs](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.0/html/api/email_in.html).

Alternatively, a [Jenkins notifier](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Buildnotifiers) could be configured to create a [bugzilla ticket via xmlrpc](http://www.bugzilla.org/releases/3.0/new-features.html#v30_feat_xml) (I don't know of an existing jenkins plugin that does this, however.)

Comment: Thanks Michael! I like the ideia of sending an email to bugzilla. I will try that.